# Show only child div, hide all others

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit new to jQuery but I have the following:

```
<div class="team-member">
   <p>John Doe</p>
   <div class="team-member-text"Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
...several others...
   <div class="team-member">
   <p>Jane Doe</p>
   <div class="team-member-text"Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

I have the team-member-text divs all set to `display:none`.When user clicks on a team-member div, I want to expand that child `team-member-text` div and hide any open `team-member-text` divs on the page.

I have this working EXCEPT for the hide part.  This is what I have.

```
jQuery( ".team-member" ).click(function() {
    jQuery('.team-member-text').not(this).hide();  //hide everything that isn't this one
    jQuery(this).find(".team-member-text").show( "slow", function() { 
       //toggle this one
    }); 
});
```

When you click again it hides then redisplays.

I found similar questions, but they didn't seem to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not the `.team-member-text` element, but the `.team-member` element.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $( ".team-member" ).on('click', function() {

        var thisOne = $(this).find(".team-member-text");

        $('.team-member-text').not(thisOne).hide();

        thisOne.show( "slow", function() {  });

    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense.  This worked with one change to the last line (changing show to toggle): thisOne.toggle( "slow", function() {  });  

So that a 2nd click would close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this way also.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".team-member").click(function() {
         $("div.team-member-text").not($(this).find("div.team-member-text")).hide();
         $(this).find("div.team-member-text").show();
         //or
         $(this).siblings("div.team-member").find("div.team-member-text")).hide();    
     });
});
```

### A little bit of explanation for you

---

On clicking `team-member` div I am checking for all `team-member-text` div but which is not current one's child and hiding them.

Next I am showing the current one's child.

Another way you can do is to check all sibling div `team-member` and find their children to hide them.